# Difference between Null and Empty String in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe4

I have a following firebird dataset:

```
ds1 : TpFIBDataset;
```

**DFM file:**

```
object ds1ID: TFIBIntegerField
 FieldName = 'ID'
end
object ds1FIELD_VALUE: TFIBStringField
  FieldName = 'FIELD_VALUE'
  Size = 250
end
```

In my Firebird database: ID is integer field and FIELD_VALUE is varchar field.

**Delphi 7:** Data is being inserted like this

```
ds1.InsertRecord([123, anyValue]);
```

here `anyValue : variant;`

If anyValue = null, null is getting inserted into the database which is the required functionality.

**In Delphi XE4**, I am doing same like this:

```
ds1.Insert;
ds1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := 123;
ds1.FieldByName('FIELD_VALUE').AsString := anyValue;
ds1.Post;
```

I get error: `could not convert variant of type (null) into type (OleStr)`

When I try like this

```
ds1.Insert;
ds1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := 123;
ds1.FieldByName('FIELD_VALUE').AsString := VarToStr(anyValue);
ds1.Post;
```

Empty string is inserted into the database, but I need null there. What and where should I make change to accomplish this task.

Comment: Do not cast it `AsString` but use `Value` then. Or if that `TpFIBDataset` supports some setting which converts empty string to `NULL`, use that and try to keep `AsString` casting.

Comment: When you say, "I am doing same" that appears not to be true. Your D7 code does `ds1.InsertRecord([123, anyValue]);`. You don't do that in the XE4 code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - By saying that, I mean I am trying to achieve same functionality but in Delphi XE4 way. Sorry for the creating the confusion.

Comment: @TLama - We can set EmptyStrToNull property of the field FIELD_VALUE in the dataset, but is not working at all.

Comment: `ds1.FieldByName('FIELD_VALUE').Clear` will set the value to `NULL`, I think

Comment: `ds1.FieldByName('FIELD_VALUE').Value := anyValue;` will also set it to NULL, as TLama already pointed out. But does XE4 not have the `InsertRecord` method? [The XE4 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.InsertRecord) does list it. (Edit: oh, I see your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926521/validation-constraints-error-while-posting-a-dataset-in-delphi-xe4-and-firebird).)

Comment: @TLama - "Value" is storing null in database :) TLama and David, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that although `null` & `''` are not equivalent in Firebird, this is not the case in all databases. (e.g. Oracle.)

Comment: @HughJones "e.g. Oracle"? Are there any database systems other than Oracle that do this? I thought Oracle was the only one, and pretty much only for backwards compatibility reasons (with other Oracle versions, dating to before there was any SQL standard)

Comment: @hvd It is quite possible that Oracle is the only one, I cannot give you an authoritative answer, but as I understand it Oracle follows the ISO standard which is why I supposed there are others.

Comment: @hvd - I have just been checking my last comment and am not so sure now that Oracle IS ISO compliant - I will keep checking ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use

```
ds1.FieldByName('FIELD_VALUE').Value := anyValue;
```

instead of

```
ds1.FieldByName('FIELD_VALUE').AsString := anyValue;
```

There is some difference in this delphi versions. Starting from delphi2006 there is another memory manager that works more precise. In example in delphi 7 and lower you can assign NULL to string or integer value. And comparision NULL with 0 will return true. In greater versions you can't do this. Null is not equal 0 or empty string.

Comment: It has nothing to do with memory manager. Also, are you sure you could ever assign `NULL` to integer value in Delphi ? I'm sure in Delphi 7 (about which is this question) above you can't. But now the worst, `FieldByName` returns a reference to a `TField` object and you're assigning a variant value to it. That won't end up with happy end. I'm not voting down but this answer is wrong.

Comment: Tnx a lot, I forgot about .Value. Now added it.